# How to connect 2 devices to single USART?

Tags: avr

I have GPS receiver connected to `ATMega328 USART RX/TX` pins. However, I also need to use `RX/TX` pins for ATMega firmware upgrade through bootloader, so `RX/TX` is connected to `FT232`.

How to properly connect both GPS Receiver and `FT232` to `ATMega RX/TX`? I can't use jumper solution, because user doesn't have access to PCB.

**Update:**

No software UART, please.
The more simple solution, the better. I need to maintain the cost and PCB size.

Comment: If you're going to rule out all hardware and software solutions, perhaps you should edit the question to reflect what the allowed universe of answers might be.

Comment: I agree with Dave. There is really no other way than what is suggested here. Either get a second USART by software or find a way to multiplex it.

Comment: @Gustavo Litovsky: So how multiplex? I would need some reference circuit, if possible.

Comment: @Pablo: Look at Olin's answer, he has the idea right there. Using a mux is likely the easiest approach. Look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer

TI has many muxes:
http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/switches-multiplexers/analog-switch-multiplexer-less-product.page

Comment: I think the comment is that the end user doesn't have access to mode-change anything on the PCB, not that the designer doesn't have the ability to customize it.

Comment: If MCU only can detect that FTDI is active, then maybe I can connect FET transistor in series with `GPS -> Atmega` line and shut down data on that line? Or better solution to cut the GPS line?

Comment: You say you want minimal cost and board size, so why isn't software UART for receiving the GPS stream not a reasonable option?

Comment: @Olin Lathrop: software UART has certain drawbacks, such as a) it will increase code size of bootloader. I have not much space left. b) it's less reliable comparing with hardware UART and slower. c) 16 bit timer is sacrificed, while I already have something on that timer in BL. I thought solution of using single USART will not be so complicated. If it goes beyond some point of course I may consider using software uart and limit some of the functionality of the software. But it looks like I have to detect FTDI is connected and shut down GPS, which shouldn't be "expensive"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to do very little.  It sounds like the FT232 and the GPS won't be used at the same time, which makes things easier.  The micro's TX pin can simply drive both.  Some sort of ORing logic can be used so that the RX line can be driven low from either of the two sources.  This could a single AND gate, for example.

It looks like the only issue will be to make sure the GPS doesn't babble during a firmware update.  Does the GPS only start sending in response to a setup message?  Can the processor hold it in reset?  Can the processor control the GPS power?  In the last case, keep in mind that the GPS's transmit line would need to float high somehow.  A outright 2-input mux may be easier then.

Comment: Yes, I won't be using FT232 and GPS at the same time. GPS starts sending messages to ATMega whenever powered on, even if it doesn't have coverage. It doesn't have reset pin unfortunately. GPS is connected to 3.3V VR and for MCU to control the power I need additional ICs, which isn't good.

Comment: My comment's first sentence was ambiguous. Actually `FT232` and `GPS` are acting same time! Which makes things complicated?

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a hardware multiplexer chip that's controlled by a GPIO output pin, or use the SoftwareSerial library to receive the GPS data on a different pin.

Comment: I am aware of SoftSerial. However, using hardware serial is more reliable, less code. Also using additional IC is not preferable if possible.

Comment: An extra chip - multiplexor or simple logic gate - is likely to cost very little.  You can use a GPIO from the atmega to switch to GPS mode once your program starts up, having it default to programming mode otherwise (ie, while the bootloader is running).

Comment: @Chris Stratton: would `74LS157` do the job?

Comment: @Chris Stratton: also somehow MCU should know that FTDI is connected, so it can send GPS shutdown. Do you know how to accomplish it?

Comment: The MCU doesn't need to know.  Make it so that when the processor is reset into the bootloader, the FT232 is connected by electrical default, and when your code starts up it intentionally switches to the GPS.